# I can not clone a git repository from team foundation server with visual studio 2013

Tags: git, tfs

After I migrated our projects from VisualSVN to Team Foundation Server 2013 Express by following the instructions if this page: [How easy it’s to migrate SVN to TFS 2013 (Git Repo)](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/2013/08/how-easy-its-to-migrate-svn-to-tfs-2013-git-repo/) , i got all the data inside our Team Foundation Server. I can see them using the web interface and browsing throw the code. 
But if I connect to this team project with a visual studio 2013 (tested this on different machines) and click "clone" to start my work, it only says that the repository is cloned now and shows a progress bar with the text "receiving objects (0/72576)..." but nothing happends.

Does anyone have any suggestions what the problem could be?

Comment: I tried to fetch the data from the tfs git repository by using git on command line. But then i get the following error: 
remote:  Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Foundation Server
remote:
remote: Eine nicht negative Zahl ist erforderlich.
Parametername: offset
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed

english: "a not negative number is neccessary"

someone have any idea whats going wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by updating Team Foundation Server to Update 4